# If else inside if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why I cant go to my next else statement in `alert('else combo')`?

```
   if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch).length == 0) {
                    console.log('if branchName');
                    $('#zzz').append(
                            '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' +
                            '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + '">' + branchList.branch + '</span>' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>'
                    );
                    if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim).length == 0) {
                        console.log('if combo');
                        $('#branchName' + branchList.branch).append(
                            '<ul>' +
                                '<li>' +
                                '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim + '">' + branchList.combo + '</span>' +
                                '</li>' + 
                                '</ul>'
                        );
                        if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + xtrim.categoryTrim).length == 0) {
                            console.log('if category');
                            $('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim).append(
                                '<ul>' +
                                    '<li>' +
                                    '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + branchList.category + '">' + branchList.category + '</span>' +
                                    '</li>' +
                                    '</ul>'
                            );
                            if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'item' + xtrim.itemTrim).length == 0) {
                                console.log('if item');
                                $('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + xtrim.categoryTrim).append(
                                    '<ul>' +
                                        '<li>' +
                                        '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'item' + xtrim.itemTrim + '">' + branchList.item + '</span>' +
                                        '</li>' +
                                        '</ul>'
                                );
                            } else {
                                alert('else item');
                                $('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'item' + xtrim.itemTrim).append(
                                   '<ul>' +
                                   '<li>' +
                                   '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'item' + xtrim.itemTrim + '">' + branchList.item + '</span>' +
                                   '</li>' +
                                   '</ul>'
                                      );
                            }
                        } else {
                           alert('else category');
                           $('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + xtrim.categoryTrim).append(
                           '<ul>' +
                               '<li>' +
                               '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'item' + xtrim.itemTrim + '">' + branchList.item + '</span>' +
                               '</li>' +
                               '</ul>'
                       );
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('else combo');
                        $('#branchName'+ branchList.branch+'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim).append(
                            '<ul>' +
                                '<li>' +
                                '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + xtrim.categoryTrim + '">' + branchList.category + '</span>' +
                                '</li>' +
                                '</ul>'
                        );
                    }
                } 
                else {
                   console.log('else branch');
                    $('#branchName' + branchList.branch).append(
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' +
                            '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim + '">' + branchList.combo + '</span>' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>'
                    );
                }
```

Comment: This code is just begging to be refactored, to remove the redundancy, and to simplify the `if`/`else` structure (if not do the lookup an entirely different and more efficient way). (Never mind it seems to have zero to do with C#)

Comment: oh okay, thanks for the help. Ill try another statement

Comment: tnx for the edit Tyress

Comment: @PeterDuniho Never mind it seems to have zero to do with C# - yeah true :D my bad sry hehe , I now know wt is my problem and I solve it already. Thanks again

Comment: Too difficult to read this. At least refactor the creation of the html - something like `function CreateListItem(id, text) { return $('<ul></ul>').append($('<li></li>').append($('<span></span>').text(text).attr('id', id))); }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke wt about my below answer there? that is near of my output

Comment: I don't know - too much code to wade through and not really sure what the logic is anyway. The above code was just a suggestion to reduce you code significantly e.g. `$('#zzz').append(CreateListItem('branchName', branchList.branch));` 1 line vs 6

Comment: thanks man, bdw the short logic is if this exists append to this else create new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
  if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch).length == 0) {
                    alert('if branchName');
                    $('#zzz').append(
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' +
                            '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + '">' + branchList.branch + '</span>' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>'
                    );
                }
                else if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim).length == 0) {
                    alert('if combo');
                    $('#branchName' + branchList.branch).append(
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' +
                            '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim + '">' + branchList.combo + '</span>' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>'
                    );
                }
                else if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + xtrim.categoryTrim).length == 0) {
                    alert('if category');
                    $('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'combo' + xtrim.comboTrim).append(
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' +
                            '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + branchList.category + '">' + branchList.category + '</span>' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>'
                    );
                }
                else if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'item' + xtrim.itemTrim).length == 0) {
                    alert('if item');
                    $('#branchName' + branchList.branch + 'category' + xtrim.categoryTrim).append(
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' +
                            '<span id="branchName' + branchList.branch + 'item' + xtrim.itemTrim + '">' + branchList.item + '</span>' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>'
                    );
                }
```

Comment: this is close to the output i want. maybe ill try to figure it out on my own. hard to be alone